# What effects does the weather have in SimCity 2000?

Tags: simcity-2000

The window showing the currently selected tools also displays the weather. I know that certain weather like tornado warning are indication for random disasters, but what effects does the other, everyday weather like sunny, cloudy or raining have on the city?

I'm playing the DOS version on DOSBox running on an Android tablet.

Comment: Wow, aDOSBox can run SimCity? I obviously need to check that out.

Comment: there was a DOS version of SimCity 2000?

Comment: @MatthewRead Sure. There's no sound, and the controls can be a bit awkward, but it does work - http://i.stack.imgur.com/ICi9R.jpg

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Excerpted from an [electronic copy of the manual](http://www.lemonamiga.com/games/docs.php?id=1450) (which appears to be hosted on a retro Amiga gaming website, but the manual text was identical across versions except for perhaps the Mac version, if I recall correctly):

> Even though you don't see the seasons change or the rains fall, and
>   you     don't feel the wind blow (other than an occasional tornado or
>   hurricane),     there is a climate model in SimCity 2000 that affects
>   your city. Weather     reports are available in the newspapers.
>
> Weather trends are generated on a monthly basis, when the
>   simulation     looks at the current trend and the season and throws in
>   a certain     weighted random element and decides the next trend. The
>   different trends     are: cold, clear, hot, foggy, chilly, overcast,
>   snowy, rainy, windy,     blizzard, hurricane and tornado. Blizzard,
>   hurricane and tornado are the     least likely to occur.
>
> Each trend has a temperature, a wind and a humidity element. In
>   general,     temperature affects the water supply, the availability of
>   solar power,     and the likelihood of fires and riots; wind affects
>   the availability of     wind power, and humidity affects the water
>   supply. These effects combine     in various ways in the various
>   trends.

I don't remember ever really noticing any of the more subtle effects described above, but I was pretty young when I played SC2k regularly.

Comment: Wow, I always thought the weather reports were just randomly-generated news ticker filler. I had no idea there was a whole subsystem that had effects on the city.

Answer (score -1):

The only version of the game to contain weather was the Super Nintendo Version, as well as the Saturn version. It actually has visible rain and snow fall in those ports.